# Treat check-boxes like radio buttons in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

**Problem:** we have a group of check-boxes.i want only one checked at a time(like as radio button).

I am doing like this.

In **View**

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-change="checkOne('1')" />
    <div ng-if="first">
         <label>Hi</label>
    </div>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-change="checkOne('2')" />
    <div ng-if="second">
         <label>Adem</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In **Controller**

```
function controller(){
   $scope.checkOne=function(val){
     if(val == '1'){
        $scope.first=true;
        $scope.second=false;
       }
     if(val == '2'){
        $scope.second=true;
        $scope.first=false; 
       }
   }
}
```

But it is not working.it selects both the check-boxes.

Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Your angular is not being called. I think your function checkOne not being called?? Add alert and check... I have postedthe answer you can check

Comment: I have included angular and controller also ,and my function checkOne is calling on checking or unchecking of checkbox.but its $scope.first = false is not unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: @PankajYadav why you don't single ng-model for both the check boxes

Comment: Can i ask... Why don't you use radio buttons itself instead of checkboxes..

Comment: Because i need check / uncheck facility,Thanks to all ,i resolved the issue ,problem is the primitives values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="controller">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-change="checkOne('1')" />
<div ng-if="first">
     <label>Hi</label>
</div>
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-change="checkOne('2')" />
<div ng-if="second">
     <label>Adem</label>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

script.js

```
  function controller($scope) {

  $scope.checkOne=function(val){
    if(val == '1'){
    $scope.first=true;
    $scope.second=false;
   }
   if(val == '2'){
    $scope.second=true;
    $scope.first=false; 
   }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Reena , I am trying exactly what you suggest me.It is not updating check box.

Comment: @PankajYadav can you share plunker

Comment: have you added alert and check if your function is being called

Comment: I think you haven't mention about the ngdialog. Provide plunker if you can

Comment: Sorry ,I am not using plunker.

Comment: it is working in plunker or simple view but why is not working in ngDialog.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/WEn4CBXA3RvtZ33VuPyM?p=preview

You need to use `ng-checked`.
I also set any checked checkboxes to be disabled so that they can't be unchecked.
After that, a simple function with a switch statement to toggle all of them on ng-click.

Controller:

```
$scope.firstCheck = true;
$scope.checkToggle = function(checkbox) {
switch (checkbox) {
  case 'first': 
    $scope.firstCheck = true;
    $scope.secondCheck = false;
    $scope.thirdCheck = false;
    break;
    case 'second': 
    $scope.firstCheck = false;
    $scope.secondCheck = true;
    $scope.thirdCheck = false;
    break;
    case 'third': 
    $scope.firstCheck = false;
    $scope.secondCheck = false;
    $scope.thirdCheck = true;
    break;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="firstCheck" ng-click="checkToggle('first')" ng-model="first" ng-checked="firstCheck"  />
<div ng-if="first">
     <label>Hi</label>
</div>
<br/><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="secondCheck" ng-click="checkToggle('second')" ng-model="second" ng-checked="secondCheck" />
<div ng-if="second">
     <label>Adem</label>
</div>
<br/><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="thirdCheck" ng-click="checkToggle('third')" ng-model="third" ng-checked="thirdCheck" />
<div ng-if="third">
     <label>something else</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks tpie, the problem was primitive type. i set the model as a property of an object as (status.firstCheck).

Comment: If you had a different solution you should post it as an answer to your question.

Comment: [link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/WEn4CBXA3RvtZ33VuPyM?p=preview)
In Some Case It is not working,Please Check Below Image
![Valid XHTML](http://www.clipular.com/c/6173593002311680.png?k=7VQIEcjtf5a28orvMqJcsRupQCE)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox Treat as RadioButton : Here We have four checkbox, and all should be work as RadioButton. Checkbox with ng-change is use for change value of ng-model.

http://plnkr.co/edit/yTJUZcFoLsSEBjruRuEY?p=preview

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.first = false;
  $scope.second = false;
  $scope.third = false;
  $scope.fourth = false;
});
```

HTML

```
 <div>{{first}}|{{second}}|{{third}}|{{fourth}}
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-change="second=false;third = false;fourth = false;"  />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-change="first = false;third = false;fourth = false;" />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="third" ng-change="first =false;second = false;fourth = false;" />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fourth" ng-change="first = false;second = false;third = false;" />
</div>
```